# BCryptPasswordEncoder not working after upgrade to spring secrity 5

Tags: spring, spring-security

after upgrading
- spring: 4.3.23.RELEASE -> 5.1.6.RELEASE
- spring-security: 4.2.12.RELEASE -> 5.1.5.RELEASE
My implementation of BCryptPasswordEncoder does not work anymore.

WARN [o.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder:  90] Encoded password does not look like BCrypt

i added some logging to get rawPassword, encodedPassword

spring4:
test1234,$2a$10$vcwRRfjPKrnXoGhDlGzJUe8ntNJEcWlHqc1l8QiDmwroB3WkJ96ma

spring5/5.1:
1a7emcO6sXmV,1a7emcO6sXmV

So the problem is that the method is called with some already encoded or hashed version of the password? I cannot find this behavior anywhere documented. How to turn it off? Of course the password matches in some magic way but i did not get the case-insensitive behavior.

```java
public class IgnoreCaseBcryptPasswordEncoder extends BCryptPasswordEncoder {

    Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(getClass());

    @Override
    public String encode(CharSequence rawPassword) {
        return super.encode(rawPassword.toString().trim().toLowerCase());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean matches(CharSequence rawPassword, String encodedPassword) {
        logger.trace(rawPassword + "," + encodedPassword);
        logger.trace(Arrays.toString(new Throwable().getStackTrace()));
        return super.matches(rawPassword.toString().toLowerCase(), encodedPassword);
    }
}
```

and XML Config:

```xml
    <bean id="passwordEncoder" class="de.k2interactive.qeep.security.oauth2.IgnoreCaseBcryptPasswordEncoder"/>

    <sec:authentication-manager id="userAuthentificationManager">
        <sec:authentication-provider user-service-ref="customUserDetailsService">
            <sec:password-encoder ref="passwordEncoder" />
        </sec:authentication-provider>
    </sec:authentication-manager>

    <oauth:authorization-server token-endpoint-url="/oauth/token" client-details-service-ref="clientDetails" token-services-ref="tokenServices">
        <oauth:authorization-code />
        <oauth:implicit />
        <oauth:refresh-token />
        <oauth:client-credentials />
        <oauth:password authentication-manager-ref="userAuthentificationManager"/>
        <oauth:custom-grant token-granter-ref="qeepFacebookLogin"/>
        <oauth:custom-grant token-granter-ref="qeepGoogleLogin"/>
        <oauth:custom-grant token-granter-ref="qeepAccountKitLogin"/>
    </oauth:authorization-server>

    <oauth:client-details-service id="clientDetails">
        <oauth:client client-id="trusted-ios-client" authorized-grant-types="password,facebook_access_token,accountkit,authorization_code,refresh_token,implicit"
                      secret="XXXcutXXX" authorities="ROLE_CLIENT, ROLE_TRUSTED_CLIENT" /> 
        <oauth:client client-id="trusted-android-client" authorized-grant-types="password,facebook_access_token,google_access_token,accountkit,authorization_code,refresh_token,implicit"
                      secret="XXXcutXXX" authorities="ROLE_CLIENT, ROLE_TRUSTED_CLIENT" />                      
    </oauth:client-details-service>
```

Stacktrace (Spring5):

```java
[de.k2interactive.qeep.security.oauth2.IgnoreCaseBcryptPasswordEncoder.matches(IgnoreCaseBcryptPasswordEncoder.java:31), 
org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider.additionalAuthenticationChecks(DaoAuthenticationProvider.java:90),
org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.java:166),
org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:175),
org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:200),
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:180),
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107),
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334),
org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:74),
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107),
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334),
org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56),
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107),
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334),
org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105),
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334),
org.springframework.security.web.access.channel.ChannelProcessingFilter.doFilter(ChannelProcessingFilter.java:157),
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334),
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215),
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178),
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357),
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270),
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193),
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166),
org.springframework.web.filter.AbstractRequestLoggingFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractRequestLoggingFilter.java:262),
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107),
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193),
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166),
org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:109),
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193),
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166),
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:200),
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96),
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490),
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139),
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92),
org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:678),
org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(RemoteIpValve.java:679),
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74),
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343),
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408),
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66),
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:836),
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2120),
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49),
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149),
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624),
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61),
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)]
```

Comment: Are you sure that you are sending plain password with your request? Could you add request with headers to your question?

Comment: There is nothing special with the request, i do it with postman:

POST {{baseurl}}/api/oauth/token?grant_type=password&scope=trust

body:
username
password

headers:
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Authorization:Basic XXXXXXXXXXXXX
Accept-Language
Qeep-Api-Version: 15
Qeep-Client-Build: 42

And everything is fine with rollback to latest spring+security 4

Comment: You didn't say that you are using OAuth2. You have to show your authorization server configuration (with configured clienst). I thought, you are using the password encoder for your user password, but you are using it for your client password.

Comment: Sorry, thats true, i am using latest spring-security-oauth2:2.3.6.RELASE. The oauth-token and registration api call is secured with client-credentials and all other requests with the users oauth token.

Comment: I added the authorization-server and client-details above.

Comment: Im still using that dependency org.springframework.security.oauth:spring-security-oauth2:2.3.6.RELEASE is it recommended to migrate to the spring-security-oauth2-client?

Comment: I also read that client secret must be encryptet, maybe that is the cause for the warning...

Answer (score 0):

I found out what the problem is:
If you are not using DelegatingPasswordEncoder, the passwordEncoder with the id passwordEncoder is not only used for matching the users password, but also for the client-secret (without beeing explicitely referenced, just by autoconfig (beanid)). For the oauth encoded users password everything is fine, but the client-secret is not oauth encoded in xml.
hack in match method demonstrates this:

```
    @Override
    public boolean matches(CharSequence rawPassword, String encodedPassword) {
        if (encodedPassword.startsWith("$2")) { //bcrypt encoded for the users password
            return super.matches(rawPassword.toString().toLowerCase(), encodedPassword);
        } else {
            return rawPassword.equals(encodedPassword); //plain-text (noop encoder) for the client-secret
        }
    }
```

So i see 2 solutions:
1.) oauth encode client-secret
2.) using DelegatingPasswordEncoder with oauth as default and {noop} prefix in client-secret.